# Display certain languages in a page

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Does there is a way to display certain languages in some pages while hiding other languages?
for example two languages out of four just in two pages of the website?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to show the flags in a module this can be achieved with php by monitoring the url, there are no such configuration through administrator. If you do not want to hack actual files, you may achieve that by adding multiple language modules and assigning them accordingly. For example make 2 modules for language selection, one with two languages and another with four. Then assign then to menu items you like them to show up.

Comment: that what i did , thank you for your help
however i cannot control the tap directly , i have to create a redirect page , which i dont like so much.

Comment: you could use something like Advanced Module Manager, to avoid redirects